# Relativity - Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity

Can someone show me how the Lorentz transformation can be derived from the metric equation:
$s^2=c^2t^2-x^2$

Comment: View the hyperbolic geometry derivation on the corresponding wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations

Comment: The derivation isn't hard, but it's somewhat tedious. If you Google for "derive lorentz transformation from metric" there's an article at http://www.physicsinsights.org/derive_lorentz.html that goes through it.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12664/2451

Answer (score 2):

Look, I will give you the derivation the same as Einstein used. It is historical derivation and consist of redundant postulate about the invariance of speed of light. If you want, I can give to you other method, which uses group axioms and is more fundamentally.

If you don't want details, you can directly see the fourth step.

**The first step**.

The first step is common to the two methods. In the beginning we analyze two-dimensional transformations (which can be easy generalized on the case of 4-space-time). Let's have two transformations
$$
x' = f(x, u, t),\quad t' = g(x, u, t), 
$$
where $u = const$ is the relative speed between two frames. 
Let's use the postulate of homogeneous space-time: according to it, the $x'$ differential (for t' - analogically)
$$
dx' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt
$$
doesn't depend on point (x, t), in which we want to calculate it. So 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = A(u), \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = B(u),
$$
and
$$
x' = Ax + Bt, \quad t' = Cx + Dt \qquad (.1)
$$

**The second step**.

Let's have transformations in 4-space-time: for $\mathbf v || Ox$, by using step 1,
$$
x' = Ax + By + Cz + Dt, \quad y' = A_{1}x + B_{1}y + C_{1}z + D_{1}t, \quad  z' = A_{2}x + B_{2}y + C_{2}z + D_{2}t, \quad t' = A_{3}x + B_{3}y + C_{3}z + D_{3}t. \qquad (.2)
$$
Because $x'$-asis is always matches with $x$-asis, $y' = 0 \Rightarrow y = 0, \quad z' = 0 \Rightarrow z = 0$. So from $(.2)$ we can get
$$
0 = A_{1}x + C_{1}z + D_{1}t, \quad 0 = A_{2}x + B_{2}y + D_{2}t.
$$
For a case of arbitrary $x, y, z, t$ from these explessions follows statement, that $A_{1} = C_{1} = D_{1} = A_{2} = B_{2} = D_{2} = 0$.
Then, 
$$
y' = B_{1}(u)y, \quad z_{1} = C_{2}(u)z,
$$
where $B_{1}, C_{2}$ are the even functions (in a reason of postulate of isotropic space).

If we use relativity principle, we can get
$$
y = B_{1}(-u)y' = B_{1}(-u)B_{1}(u)y = B_{1}^{2}(u)y \Rightarrow B_{1}^{2} = 1 . 
$$
By using identity transform, $y'(u = 0) = y \Rightarrow B_{1} = 1$.

This result leads to the statement, that $y, z$ don't mixes with each other. This means that $B_{1} = C_{1} = B_{3} = C_{3} = 0$. So, finally, for $(.2)$ we can get that
$$
x' = Ax + Bt, \quad y' = y, \quad z' = z, \quad t' = Cx + Dt.  \qquad (.3)
$$

**The third step**.

We can use principle of homogeneous space-time one more time for getting the relations of $A, B, C, D$.
First, let's have system in which $x' = 0$. For this case $x = ut $, and we have from $(.3)$
$$
\begin{cases}
    0 =  Aut + Bt \Rightarrow B = -Au \qquad (.4) \\
    t' = Cx + Dt \\
\end{cases}.
$$
Let's have system in which $x = 0$. Then $x' = -ut'$, and
$$
\begin{cases}
    -ut' = Bt \Rightarrow B = -\frac{ut'}{t} = -uD \qquad (.5) \\
    t' = Dt \Rightarrow \frac{t'}{t} = D \\
\end{cases}.
$$
From $(.4), (.5)$ follows that $A = D = \gamma (u)$, where $\gamma (u)$ is an unknown function of speed, $B = -Au$, and $C$ we can write as $D\frac{C}{D} = D\sigma (u)$. Finally,
$$
x' = \gamma (x - ut), \quad t' = \gamma (t - \sigma x), \quad y' = y, \quad z' = z . \qquad (.6)
$$

**The fourth step**.

Let's have the spherical wave equations in two frames,
$$
x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = c^{2}t^{2}, \quad x'^{2} + y'^{2} + z'^{2} = c^{2}t'^{2}. \qquad (.7)
$$
By substitution $(.6)$ into $(.7)$ and we can get
$$
\gamma^{2}x^{2} -2\gamma^{2}uxt + \gamma^{2}u^{2}t^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = c^{2}\gamma^{2}t^{2} - 2\sigma \gamma^{2}c^{2}xt + \gamma^{2}\sigma^{2}x^{2}c^{2}t^{2}. \qquad (.8)
$$
For getting the sphere equation in the $S$ frame we must to identify $2\gamma^{2}uxt$ and $2\sigma \gamma^{2}c^{2}xt$. So
$$
\sigma = \frac{u}{c^{2}}.
$$
Then $(.8)$ will reduce to
$$
\gamma^{2}\left( 1 - \frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = c^{2}t^{2}\gamma^{2}\left(1 - \frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}} \right) \Rightarrow \gamma^{2} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}.
$$
So, by using identity $x'(u = 0) = x \Rightarrow \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$, we finally can get for $(.6)$
$$
x' = \frac{x - ut}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}}, \quad t' = \frac{t - \frac{u}{c^{2}}x}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For a boost in the $x$ direction, propose a linear transformation such that

$$t'=t'(x,t)=ax+bt \\
x'=x'(x,t)=cx+dt $$

Impose the constraint

$$c^2t^2-x^2=c^2(t')^2-(x')^2 $$

Solve for $a,b,c,d$

About the linearity of the Lorentz transformations, you may check Gravitation and Cosmology by Weinberg p.27.

Comment: You need to explain why it should be linear

Comment: @LarryHarson added reference about that matter