# Lorentz transformation, non linear space transformations

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

The Lorentz transformation is linear in $x,y,z,t$.

Are there are any non linear space transformations that leaves the speed of light constant in all inertial frames? The possibility being that space or matter might not transform in a simple homogeneous way.

Such a transformation which leaves the Maxwell equations invariant I imagine is unlikely.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12664/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105379/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155363/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253356/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The question and the respective answer by Qmechanic pointed out by ACuriousMind explicitly assume that (1) there is a spacetime viewed as a (2)  differential manifold equipped with (3) a metric constructed by exploiting the constant light velocity postulate. The question above does not assume all these physical hypotheses. I do not believe that it is a duplicate even if some overlap exists.

Comment: Agree with Valter Moretti comments.  I am thinking of non linear transformations. The possible duplicates referred to deal more with proving the linearity of the LT I think,  a different subject.