# Killing field in Minkowski space-time

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

If we look at the killing equation for a vector field $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^{(p,q)}$ (or on an open subset thereof) in coordinates with constant diagonal pseudo-metric we get:

$$X_{\mu,\nu}+X_{\nu,\mu}=0 \tag{1}$$

In the case $\mu=\nu$ it is clear that this implies $X^\mu$ does not depend on the coordinate $q^\mu$. In the book I am reading it is remarked that the equation also implies that $X^\mu$ in general can be put in the form:

$$X^\mu=c^\mu+\omega^\mu_\nu q^\nu$$

Where (1) implies for $\omega$:

$$\omega^Tg+g\omega=0$$

where $g$ is the metric.

My question is, why does the Killing equation imply that $X$ is *linear* in the chosen coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a consequence of the connection on $\mathbb{R}^n$ being flat.

One can give the $\omega$ in $X = c + \omega x$ explicitly as $\omega_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu X_\nu$, and the $c$ as $c = X - \omega x$.

For a Killing field $X$, one has that $\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu X_\rho = {R^\sigma}_{\mu\nu\rho}X_\sigma$, where $R$ is the Riemann tensor, but $R=0$ for flat connections, so $\partial_\mu\omega_{\nu\sigma} = \partial_\mu\partial_\nu X_\sigma = 0$, i.e. $\omega$ is constant.

Evaluating $\partial_\mu c_\nu$, one also finds that $c$ is constant if $\omega$ is antisymmetric, and $\partial_\mu X_\nu$ is antisymmetric by virtue of the Killing equation.

Altogether, this gives $X= c+\omega x$ for $c,\omega$ constant and $\omega$ antisymmetric.

Comment: It is surprising to me that you have to use more sophisticated notions than just differentiation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (curvature). If I look at the equation given it really looks like some elementary algebraic considerations should give me the result. Is there a more pedestrian way to arrive at $\partial \partial X = 0$?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method:

1. The Killing equation 
   $$({\cal L}_X\eta)_{\mu\nu}~=~0\tag{1}$$ 
   for a constant metric 
   $$\eta_{\mu\nu}={\rm const}\tag{2}$$
   reads
   $$ X_{\mu,\nu}+X_{\nu,\mu}~=~0,\tag{3}$$
   as OP correctly mentions.
2. On the other hand consider a coordinate transformation
   $$ x^{\mu}~~\longrightarrow~~ x^{\prime \nu}~=~f^{\nu}(x), \tag{4}$$
   that preserves the metric (2), i.e.
   $$ \eta_{\mu\nu}~=~\frac{\partial x^{\prime\kappa}}{\partial x^{\mu}}\eta_{\kappa\lambda}\frac{\partial x^{\prime\lambda}}{\partial x^{\nu}}. \tag{5}$$
   Note that for an infinitesimal coordinate transformation of the form
   $$ \delta x^{\mu}~=~x^{\mu \prime}-x^{\mu}~=~ \varepsilon  X^{\mu}, \tag{6}$$
   eq. (5) becomes exactly the same eq. (3)!
3. The solutions (4) to eq. (5) is proven to be [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12664/2451) Phys.SE post using various methods.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to reply 8 years later but if you take the killing equation, differentiate wrt an arbitrary third coordinate and amtisymmetrise, you get a pair of equations which yields the result you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).