# A question from "The meaning of the relativity, by A.Einstein" - Lorentz transformations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Let $K$ and $\bar K$ be two cartesian co-orditate systems in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The element:
$$s^2=(\Delta x^1)^2+(\Delta x^2)^2+(\Delta x^3)^2$$
is an invariant in all co-ordinate system. I want prove that the relations between de co-ordinates of $K$ and $K$ must be linear.

In the book: "The meaning of relativity, by A. Einstein" we can find the following reasoning:

Suppose that $\bar x^\nu=\bar x^\nu(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ and note that:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
(\Delta x^1)^2+(\Delta x^2)^2+(\Delta x^3)^2= \text{const.}&(1)\\
(\Delta \bar x^1)^2+(\Delta \bar x^2)^2+(\Delta \bar x^3)^2 = \text{const.}&(2)
\end{array}\right.$$
Also by Taylor's theorem:
$$\Delta \bar x^\nu = \sum_\alpha \frac{\partial \bar x^\nu}{\partial x^\alpha}\Delta x^\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha,\beta} \frac{\partial^2\bar x^\nu}{\partial x^\alpha\partial x^\beta}\Delta x^\alpha\Delta x^\beta+\ldots\qquad (3)$$
Substituting $\Delta x^\nu$ given by $(2)$ to $(3)$ and compare this with $(*)$ then we deduce that $\bar x^\nu=\bar x^\nu(x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4)$ must be linear.

**Can anybody help me to take $\Delta x^\nu$ given by $(2)$ and put into $(3)$ to deduce that the transformation must be linear?**

Comment: Qmechanic gives the general argument in [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/12817/50583) (the thread contains several different methods for the linearity of the Lorentz transformations, most of the arguments apply equally well to the Euclidean/Cartesian case). It's really plugging in and noting that the higher order terms have to have properties inconsistent with them being non-zero, so they are zero.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253305/2451

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1810027/11127