# Homogeneity and Isotropy of space and time imply that coordinate transformations are linear

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

In the following reference (http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0302045), the author tries to derive a general expression for coordinate transformation between inertial frames using just the assumptions of relativity, homogeneity of space and isotropy of space and time. However, in equation 12, he says the following 
$$\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} (x_1, t, v) = \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} (x_2, t, v)$$
and concludes that since the choice of $x_1$ and $x_2$ were arbitrary, the partial derivative is a constant. 
However, shouldn't he consider it dependent on $t$ and $v$ until proven otherwise?

I know that this is a similar question to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253356/), but my question remains even after going through them. I think a better question to ask would be how homogeneity and isotropy imply linearity of coordinate transformations between inertial frames.

Comment: Aren't both sides evaluated at the  same $t,v$?

Comment: Yeah they are, nut my question is, why is $\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} (x,t,v) $ also independent of $t$ as is concluded in the paper? He says it's a constant.